# WMDC emulator connection issues

Tags: windows-7, windows-mobile, emulation, wmdc

I've got issues connecting my windows mobile 6 emulator to my computer via Window Mobile Developer Center.  I can view the files system on the device.  I can connect to mobile databases on the device.  But I cannot access the web / my local computer from the emulator.

Background: I've been using my emulators for a while now.  Maybe every other month or so, something decides it doesn't want to work any more and I have to twiddle all of the settings I can find until it starts working again.  Today, this has happened to me twice.  I fixed the issues earlier today after lots of hair-pulling, but this time, I don't know what to do any more.

Things I've tried so far:

- soft resetting the emulator
- deleting and re-adding the device partnership a la [Why is WMDC/ActiveSync so flaky?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2127666/why-is-wmdc-activesync-so-flaky)
- toggling the connection type between 'DMA' and other settings a la [How to get Windows Mobile Device Center To Connect to the Emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3506543/how-to-get-windows-mobile-device-center-to-connect-to-the-emulator)
- restarting VS
- restarting my machine
- restarting the emulator manager

No matter what I do, Pocket IE always tells me that it cannot find the website (e.g. yahoo), and my app is unable to connect to my local web site.  Any thing else I should be doing?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got the connection working now, and I wish I knew what got it working again.  Just prior to the emulator's return to functionality, I was firing-up some of the other emulators to see if they were having issues as well (they weren't).  After trying some other emulators, I went back to the one I want to use, and when I cradled the emulator, it worked.  So, maybe running and cradling some of the other emulators un-clogged something in the bowels of WMDC...